# Cups Service wont start Ubuntu16.04 lts

Tags: 16.04, networking, printing, cups-lpd

Printers have been working just fine until today, the user tried to print some thing and the only choice they geis to save to the PC. Looking at the settings for printers I hit the connect button and then I get an Cups error stating could not connect to the cups service. I have removed and reinstalled cups to no avail. I have tried to restart the service and get the unit service cups is masked. Anyone have any suggestions for Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: This is on a remote PC so it is difficult to work on but Is there an output I can add that will help here?

Answer (score 0):

After trying all of the other suggestions on the other pages I was able to get mine to work by installing the cups-daemon > then purged the cups > then installed cups > restarted cups service > rebooted > after the reboot the printers showed back up and were available again.